# using batch to find files with a wildcard and print the name to another file

Tags: loops, batch-file, wildcard

My issue is that i would like to search a folder with a wildcard and then print the name of the file in another batch file. For example: c:\docs\hello.txt (I want to look through this folder with a *.txt search criteria then pass this "hello.txt" to my env.bat with set filename=

So far i can get the filename as below:

```
echo off
cd %1
if exist filelist.txt del filelist.txt
for /r %%a in (*.txt) do echo %%a > filelist.txt
```

Comment: That seems to work, what's the question?

Comment: Why are you redirecting the output to a text file.  Just use the CALL command to execute the `env.bat` file and pass the `FOR` variable `%%a` as a command line argument to the batch file.

Comment: I want to use the name in the filelist.txt file as the filename variable. this file is also giving me the entire path to the file and I only want the filename.txt

Comment: Can you give an example of how i can use the for %%a as an argument to get the filename from the wildcard search. thanks

Comment: Type `for /?` so something like `%%~nxA` which is name and extension.

Answer (score 1):

### search.bat:

```js
@echo off & setlocal
for /r "%~dp0" %%a in (*.txt) do call env.bat "%%~nxa"
```

### env.bat:

```js
@echo off & setlocal
set "filename=%~1"

echo %filename%
```

`search.bat` will search the directory in which the script lives recursively for `*.txt`.  For every match, `env.bat` is called with an argument of the filename.txt (without the full path, if you want the full path, change `"%%~nxa"` to `"%%~fa"`.  See `help for` in a console window for more info.)  `env.bat` then echoes the variable it set.

---

Just as an academic exercise, it's also possible to pass `filename.txt` via stdin rather than as a script argument.

### search.bat:

```js
@echo off & setlocal
for /r "%~dp0" %%a in (*.txt) do (@echo %%~nxa|env.bat)
```

### env.bat

```js
@echo off & setlocal
set /P "filename="

echo %filename%
```

---

For Eric J., here are the same scripts written in powershell.  First is the argument method:

### search.ps1

```js
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
gci -recurse -filter *.txt | %{ .\env.ps1 $_.Name }
```

### env.ps1

```js
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
param (
    [string]$filename
)

$filename
```

And next is the stdin method.

### search.ps1

```js
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
gci -recurse -filter *.txt | %{ $_.Name | .\env.ps1 }
```

### env.ps1

```js
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
[string]$filename = $input

$filename
```